# How we can manually instrument the PHP code to generate a dynamic call-trace?

Tags: php, instrumentation, call-graph

Instrumentation is the process of modifying a program so that dynamic information is recorded during program execution.

What I want to know is that how I can manually instrument my PHP code to generate a dynamic call-trace ??

Answer (score 0):

Manually?

1. Add a "called-from" argument to every function/method.
2. For each
   function/method, at the entry allocate a new "Called" object"
3. Write the function name into the "Called" object
4. Make the Called object refer
   through a bi-directional link back to the called-from argument.
5. For  each function call, pass the new Called object to the callee   as
   the called-from argument.
6. In main, create a new "Called" object. remembering it as "root",
   containing "main" with a null backlink.

Now launch main.  This scheme will build a call tree at root.

This sounds really painful if you have a lot of functions.  You should automate this.  [See this paper for a scheme on how to automate this kind of instrumentation.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf)